# How to specific the builds ./gradlew test will build

Tags: testing, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

Say I have 2 different builds in my build.gradle buildTypes (debug, release). When I run the ./gradlew test command, both of those builds will be built and tested. How do I specify that I only want the 'debug' build to build and test when I run ./gradlew test?

Comment: Is that android related problem? Maybe try `buildRelease` or `assembleRelease`?

Comment: Run `./gradlew tasks` and share the output. The task You'd like to run is probably listed there.